# Retag request: ratchet-and-clank-ps4 -> ratchet-and-clank-2016

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

Insomniac Games has joined the ranks of other developers who want to make things confusing by releasing a new game with the same name as an older game (joining SEGA and Electronic Arts).

Usually how this is handled is with the game year appended to the end of the newer game (with the exception of [simcity](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/simcity)), except right now, it's being separated by the console it was released on. To me, this doesn't seem like a very good solution, because while it happens to hold in this particular case, it is inconsistent with other tagging decisions like [sonic-the-hedgehog-2006](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sonic-the-hedgehog-2006), [sw-battlefront-2015](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sw-battlefront-2015), and [tomb-raider-2013](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tomb-raider-2013).

Comment: [tag:ratchet-and-clank-ps4]

Comment: I think the only reason it's using the PS4 moniker is because that's how most articles and marketing around it seems to be distinguishing it from the movie, I.e. *'Ratchet & Clank (PS4)'*. Google even gives different results from searching '... PS4' vs '... 2016'. Even though I also prefer using '2016', the Devil's advocate standpoint would be to follow the current trend for SEO purposes

Answer (score 4):

[ratchet-and-clank-2016](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ratchet-and-clank-2016) is now the used tag, with [ratchet-and-clank-ps4](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ratchet-and-clank-ps4) as its synonym.